# PHP how to var_dump an object in a function writing into database?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use CodeIgniter and I have a function createRecord in a model:

```
public function createRecord($aRecordToSave) {
    $oLatestRecord = $this->getLatestRecord($aRecordToSave[$this->sForeignKey]);
    var_dump($oLatestRecord);
    $this->db->trans_begin();
    $this->db->where($this->sForeignKey, $aRecordToSave[$this->sForeignKey]);
    $this->db->update($this->sRecordsTable, array('latest' => 0));
  }
```

How can I display var_dump output, when the function is executed only by writing in the database and page is redirected instantly from edit by clicking save to show view?

Comment: call `exit` after you `var_dump`

Comment: @DharmaSaputra No. `exit()` will mean the transaction ( `->trans_begin()` ) is never enacted.

Comment: you can use $_SESSION['output_data'] = print_r($oLatestRecordSignature,true);

then use it

or 

return 

$this->db->update($this->sRecordsTable, array('latest' => 0));
return $oLatestRecordSignature;

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam oh you mean just like my answer? `:-D`

Comment: @Martin yes but other are other option also can use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## If you want to only output the result of your `var_dump`

`var_dump` is usually used in a debugging context and not usually for a feeback message to user context.

So; if you want to feedback the message to the user, it's easiest to use a `$_SESSION` and dump the var using [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php).

Therefore:

```
public function createRecord($aRecordToSave) {
    ....
    $_SESSION['message'] = print_r($oLatestRecordSignature,true);
    ....
  }
```

Will save your message and you can then add code to your output page to display the message, for example:

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['message'])){
     print $_SESSION['messge'];
     unset($_SESSION['message]);
}
```

## If you want to record the result of your `var_dump` and cease execution

Unlike [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php), `var_dump` doesn't let you choose where the data is output.

So; if you want to feedback the message to debug, it's easiest to use the PHP `errr_log` and dump the var. It is better to store things in the error log rather than simply output errors to screen, as you can view how the error evolves as you make changes to the code with each execution.

Therefore:

```
public function createRecord($aRecordToSave) {
    ....
    error_log(print_r($oLatestRecordSignature,true));
    error_log(print_r(debug_backtrace(),true); //optional but useful
    exit; // cease script execution. 
    ....
  }
```

You can then read this detail in your error log.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use `return` to send back `$oLatestRecordSignature` ?

Comment: @WilliamPerron That is a good point but I have no idea how the function is called and what is expected from the function. OP specifically asked for output to screen rather than feedback to whatever class or method called the function `:-/`

Comment: works great, thanks! Just a small follow up question: With your code snippet I get stdClass Object ( [document_id] => 2162 [updated_at] => 2017-12-20 14:11:41 [sort_order] => 0 . How can I retrieve only the [sort_order] value? Neither $oLatestRecordSignature->sort_order nor $oLatestRecordSignature['sort_order'] doesn't work.

Comment: @Trinity76 `print_r($oLatestRecordSignature->sort_order,true)` should work. unless sort order is a **private** variable.  ceck your error log which should tell you if a private variable is attempted to be called by `print_r`

Answer (score -2):

var_dump();die; should work just fine for this.

Comment: No. die will mean the transaction is never enacted.

Comment: @Martin That might actually be a good thing, until the `var_dump()` has done its work in helping with the debugging

Comment: @RiggsFolly possibly, but I understood the question to be that OP wanted to not interrupt the transaction.